# why does two object with same property not work the same way

Tags: javascript, html, dom

While doing a task in Javascript30 I noticed that

`document.querySelectorAll('input')[0].style.setProperty` and `document.documentElement.style.setProperty` output thesame object  but the former does not work when I try to set a property.

I want to know why the former does not work but the later does.

I did a console.log to view the output of both lines of code.

```js
let controller = document.querySelectorAll(".controller input");

//console.log(document.querySelectorAll('input')[0].style.setProperty);
//console.log(document.documentElement.style.setProperty);
function handleChange() {
  const suffix = this.dataset.sizing || "";
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--${this.name}`, this.value + suffix);
  /*document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach((input) => {
   input.style.setProperty(`--${this.name}`, this.value + suffix);
  });*/
}

controller.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('change', handleChange));
controller.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('mousemove', handleChange));
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(150, 200, 140);
}

:root {
  --blur: 10px;
  --spacing: 10px;
  --color: red;
}

img {
  padding: var(--spacing);
  filter: blur(var(--blur));
  background: var(--color);
}
```

```html
<header>Playing with CSS variables and JS</header>
<div class="controller">
  <label for="spacing">Spacing: </label>
  <input type="range" min="10" max="200" id="spacing" name="spacing" value="10" data-sizing="px">
  <label for="blur">Blur: </label>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="30" id="blur" name="blur" value="10" data-sizing="px">
  <label for="color">Base Color</label>
  <input type="color" id="color" name="color">
</div>
<img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dzwmmrwr2/image/upload/v1542708495/6_kmfxtt.png" alt="image" width="300" height="350">
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uwGMTcGzE4cS4jP4yrnr)

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your question and not only a link to an external resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is that you are selecting the 'input-elements' using the querySelector, instead of the 'html-element' as you do with `document.documentElement`

using `document.querySelectorAll('html')` instead of `document.querySelectorAll('input')` sould solve your issue:

```js
// Code goes here

let controller = document.querySelectorAll(".controller input");

function handleChange() {
  const suffix = this.dataset.sizing || "";
  document.querySelectorAll('html').forEach((input) => {
    input.style.setProperty(`--${this.name}`, this.value + suffix);
  });
}

controller.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('change', handleChange));
controller.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('mousemove', handleChange));
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(150, 200, 140);
}

:root {
  --blur: 10px;
  --spacing: 10px;
  --color: red;
}

img {
  padding: var(--spacing);
  filter: blur(var(--blur));
  background: var(--color);
}
```

```html
<header>Playing with CSS variables and JS</header>
<div class="controller">
  <label for="spacing">Spacing: </label>
  <input type="range" min="10" max="200" id="spacing" name="spacing" value="10" data-sizing="px">
  <label for="blur">Blur: </label>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="30" id="blur" name="blur" value="10" data-sizing="px">
  <label for="color">Base Color</label>
  <input type="color" id="color" name="color">
</div>
<img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dzwmmrwr2/image/upload/v1542708495/6_kmfxtt.png" alt="image" width="300" height="350">
```